# Segregation of access between "Developers" and "Provisioning Officers"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to setup AWS IAM users and groups. I want to create two groups: Developers and Provisioning Officers.

Developers should be able to use the services they have access to but not provision one by themselves.
Provisioning Officers should be able to provision AWS services.

Is there a way I could do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, but it's not easy. You can create 2 groups, one for devs and one for provisioners, then you need to attach IAM policies to each group. That's the easy part.

The hard part is knowing what permissions each group needs. What a user can do is defined in the `Action` part of the policy. You need to look into the [reference table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_actions-resources-contextkeys.html#actions_table) for each service you use and figure out which actions are "provisioning" and which are "others".

For example, you might want to restrict that only the "provisioners" can launch EC2 instances, in which case you grant `ec2:RunInstances` permission to that group and don't grant this to the other group:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
         "ec2:RunInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
   }
   ]
}
```